# Read the current position on an embed Youtube video's timeline

Tags: video, youtube, position, timeline

I have a video that I'm going to upload on Youtube (or even better, Vimeo).

I'm then gonna embed it on my website. I'd like that, when the video is played, the background color of my website changes depending on the position on the video's timeline.

For instance, the video isn't played yet : the background is black.
The video is played : the background becomes blue.
At 10 seconds, it becomes white.

Is there a way to read the position on a Youtube video and do that?

If not : is there a way to just detect when the video is played, and change the background color at this time?

Open to every language.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
player.getDuration():Number
```

Returns the duration in seconds of the currently playing video. Note that `getDuration()` will return 0 until the video's metadata is loaded, which normally happens just after the video starts playing.

If the currently playing video is a live event, the `getDuration()` function will return the elapsed time since the live video stream began. Specifically, this is the amount of time that the video has streamed without being reset or interrupted. In addition, this duration is commonly longer than the actual event time since streaming may begin before the event's start time.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information